# Open a toolbox screen on android device by scrolling from the bottom

Tags: android, swipe, gesture

I'm trying to make my app (which is some kind of toolbox) to be opened from any screen (home, other applications etc..) by swiping from the bottom. Something like the action-bar drop-down menu, but from the bottom.
I saw an app that managed to do similar thing - it was "Omni Swipe".

I tried a lot of creative ways with no success. any tips ?
Thanks,
Amit

Comment: If my answer helped you remember to up vote and accept it.

Comment: thanks, still checking it.. i will once i'll find my way :)

Answer (score 0):

If my memory doesn't betray me applications like "Omni Swipe" add their views as systems overlays. You can open up "Omnie Swipe" in the HirarchyView to see exactly what flags they use.

Also, check out the window manager for more information on you window flag priority works:
http://androidxref.com/5.1.1_r6/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/view/WindowManager.java#359

For sample code look at this stack overflow question:
[Creating a system overlay window (always on top)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4481226/creating-a-system-overlay-window-always-on-top)